# How to pivot data in T-SQL for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with the following structure where there are different types of results for a "SymbolQuoteID".

```
AnalysisResultID    SymbolQuoteID   ResultTypeID    Result            Updated
11                  368             1               48.6750775191538  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
12                  368             2               47.7401046493826  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
13                  368             3               47.3978529584944  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
14                  368             4               43.4227483517635  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
15                  369             1               44.9316592945153  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
16                  369             2               48.8348167760945  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
17                  369             3               51.6463393199821  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
18                  369             4               51.7885923247485  2015-10-08 22:09:15.680
```

I need to SELECT the data so it is formatted like this where ResultTypeID is the column header and the corresponding Result column value is the column data. There is no aggregation, just the Result value. Also, the number of values for ResultTypeID will be consistent w/in a single query but may vary from query to query. For example, one time they might be 1 through 4 and another time 1 through 7, etc. Therefore, the number of columns in the pivoted table will change based upon the data.

```
SymbolQuoteID                1                 2                 3                 4                 
368           48.6750775191538  47.7401046493826  47.3978529584944  43.4227483517635
369           44.9316592945153  48.8348167760945  51.6463393199821  51.7885923247485
```

It seems PIVOT might work but I've not used it before. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What did you tried with that `PIVOT` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic `PIVOT`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e05f/3/0)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ResultTypeID) 
        FROM tbl 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    , 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 
    'SELECT SymbolQuoteID, ' + @cols + '
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SymbolQuoteID, ResultTypeID, Result
        FROM tbl
    )t
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(Result)
        FOR ResultTypeID IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '

PRINT (@query)
EXEC (@query)
```

---

You can also do this using [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e05f/1/0)

```
DECLARE @maxResultTypeId INT
SELECT TOP 1 @maxResultTypeId = ResultTypeId FROM tbl ORDER BY ResultTypeID DESC

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    SymbolQuoteID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN ResultTypeId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), rn) + ' THEN Result  END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(rn) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT TOP(@maxResultTypeId)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS rn
    FROM sys.columns
)t

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY SymbolQuoteID'

PRINT (@sql)
EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT SymbolQuoteID   
      ,ResultTypeID    
      ,Result
FROM TableName ) t
 PIVOT (SUM(Result)
        FOR ResultTypeID
        IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
       )p
```